# The filter value for "_lt" is not a valid number

Tags: flutter, graphql, double, graphql-flutter

I don't know why the variables are not valid numbers. I use flutter with graphql_flutter plugin.

Somehow I get this error message:
[image]

The query:

[image]

The generated API classes:

[image]

[image]

The "service" function:

[image]

Function in repo:

[image]

The function call:

[image]

Comment: I belive what has happend is that your Graph QL API is returning a "_lt" as a string instead of a float as defined in the code. This might be happening where you are parsing the json to Dart code.

Comment: But it works with integer numbers.